# What methods are there to level your particle hair?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles

How can we very sharply level particle hair? The default settings are very good for random particle hair but for actually doing the opposite thing, what are the methods?
[image: blanket]
For example like the blanket above, as you can see some of the hair is pushed inside and some are way too long. How can we level them so that their hair(or fur), become more like that of a toothbrush? Sharply leveled. The idea is to create a plane leveled hair and then added with brownian and some clumps and curls settings to create a realistic blanket(using a texture as a source of color).  Here is the blend file in case the example can be clearly shown with the file itself:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Mainly, you have a non default parameter here : the brownian (agitation) field set to a value. Set it back to 0 to have a regular aspect.

After that, as you want to have a short hair (like brush), you may lower the segments (as their are used for the hair movement, mainly for long hair).

And to have more density, simply grow the amount of emitted particles.

[image]

As some faces are not visible, you should also use a vertex group to locate the hair where you want on the visible faces : in consequence, the visible faces will have more hair on them with the same or lower overall hair amount.

[image]

Comment: I have another question though. After we shape the hair using the particle settings we cannot further fine tune it in particle edit mode. Is there a way to apply the settings so that we could fine tune it in particle edit mode?

Comment: did you remodel the mesh? I copied the settings exactly in the screenshot. Since, I'd like then  hair to be visible in all faces I assigned all a vertex group:  [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1899" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1899/)

Comment: though the hair length of 2 was very long for me(I don't know how), and I had to set it to 0.2.

Comment: @BumbleBee, maybe I have applied scale or something (I dont remember)

Comment: really? No matter what I tweak it doesn't seem to work and do you know also about the question I have asked in the question above?

Comment: @BumbleBee, this last file contains several parameters which are different from your initial file : a/ in the render section "end time" set to 1 instead of 0.0something (if you want to keep 1, lower the hair length as 0.0something lower the lenght as they cannot grow). b/ in the children section mode set to 'none' instead of 'interpolated'. Understand that if you change all these numerous parameters it's not possible for someone else to give a full check each time, thanks...

Comment: sorry for the trouble. I'm very bad with particles

Comment: The problem was, the modifier was not applied

Comment: do you also know about the question mentioned in the comment above?